Airflow does not write logs to Cloud Storage
I'm working with Apache Airflow within GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine). I deployed using helm graphics.
Below is a portion of my custom settings YAML:
executor: KubernetesExecutor

airflow:
  config:
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "True"
    AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING: "True"
    AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER: gs://<my-bucket-name>/logs
    AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID: google_cloud_default
    GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS: "--workers 1 --timeout 300"

dags:
  gitSync:
    enabled: true
    repo: <my-repo>
    branch: main
    rev: HEAD
    subPath: dags
    depth: 1
    wait: 60

extraConns:
  - id: google_cloud_default
    conn_type: google_cloud_platform
    extra: '{"extra__google_cloud_platform__keyfile_dict": "${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}", "extra__google_cloud_platform__project": "${GCP_PROJECT_ID}"}'

scheduler:
  replicas: 1

web:
  replicas: 1
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 7Gi
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 16Gi
  initContainers:
    - name: wait-for-scheduler
      image: busybox
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup airflow-scheduler; do echo waiting for scheduler; sleep 2; done;']
    - name: wait-for-postgresql
      image: busybox
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup postgresql; do echo waiting for postgresql; sleep 2; done;']
  livenessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 1800
    periodSeconds: 20
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 5
  readinessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 1800
    periodSeconds: 20
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 5
  startupProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 300
    periodSeconds: 30
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    failureThreshold: 10

postgresql:
  enabled: true

flower:
  enabled: false

redis:
  enabled: false

triggerer:
  enabled: true

serviceAccount:
  create: false
  name: <MY-SA-NAME>

The problem that is occurring is that Airflow is not writing logs to the specified GCS bucket.I hid the bucket name here in the question for security reasons.
Airflow Error Message when trying to view dag execution logs (Airflow UI): dag-sincronizada-print-hello-dtp2cwfe
*** Could not read served logs: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
I expected that with the settings above, airlfow would write to and read from the cloud storage. The credentials have sufficient permissions to administer the cloud storage.
